# How to configure the delimiter for evil-search-word for C/C++ modes?

Tags: evil, delimiters

Using evil mode, pressing `*` runs `evil-search-word-forward`.

But for some reason C/C++ mode uses `_` as a delimiter, meaning `ID_FOO` will only match the first term `ID` when searching for the next term.

How to configure these delimiter characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I had:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

Set, some modes ignore this (C/C++ for example)

Found solution is to set this for spesific modes:

```
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" c-mode-syntax-table)
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w" c++-mode-syntax-table)
```